# JQuery Hide of Select Option Not Working in IE8 or IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a TextBox and a Button on which I am calling a Javascript function using JQuery selector to show or hide data in ListBox. My code is working fine in all other browsers except Internet Explorer.
**NOTE:** I am trying to do this without using Loop in my functionality.

```js
$(window).load(function () {
$("#btnSearch").live("click", function () {
        SearchListBox();
    });
});
function SearchListBox() {
    if ($("input[id*='txtSearch']").val().length >= 3) {
        $("select[id*='ddl'] >option").hide();
        var srchKey = $("input[id*='txtSearch']").val();
        $("select[id*='ddl'] >option:contains('" + srchKey + "')").show();
    }
    else if ($("input[id*='txtSearch']").val().length === 0) {
        $("select[id*='ddl'] >option").show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" title="Search with 3 or more characters" />
                    <div id='button-holder'>
                    <img src="../Images/Search.gif" id="btnSearch" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Height="250px" Width="250px" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not all browers allow you to hide `option` elements. I think Safari doesn't as well. You have to remove them and add them back. I'm sure I've posted an answer, having trouble finding it at the moment...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks Crowder, Removing and Adding the elements will impact the on the page responsiveness of my application since I have a huge data pulled from DB to bind server side control.

Answer (score 0):

I'am sure your array data that populates the select comes from some place. Work with for loop of your array data, don't work with your html directly, create a document fragment with your data in every hit of the button and delete your options and then append this fragment containing the filtered options in your select

Some idea, not exactly but works in every browser and the use of fragment is very performant.

Your for loop throught the data will call the function appendOptionToFragment

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

function appendOptionToFragment(fragment, optionText, optionValue) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.innerHTML = optionText;
    opt.value = optionValue;
    fragment.appendChild(opt);
}


  $("#someSelect > option").remove();
     var select = document.getElementById("someSelect");
    select.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, But I don't want to use loops in my function. It is effecting the performance of my page. Could you please suggest me any other alternative?

Comment: Hiding an <option> element is not in the spec. But you can disable them, which should work cross-browser.

Comment: I see that you use WebForms and bindings. Your problem is that you don't want to overwork your already received data, in that case your options are disable not wanted elements with javascript or have a page that behaves like a controller and return your list in a json array structure and then you could use my solution , I already used it that way some time in the past and works well for that case filling large dropdowns